# Pull value from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to create two tables that are related.  The `ITEM` table has a primary key of `ItemNumber` and another important column of `UnitPrice`.  The second Table has the `UnitPrice` again.  I want to populate the `UnitPrice` column in the `ORDER_LINE_ITEM` table from the value in the `ITEM` `UnitPrice` column but am not sure how to do this.  I need to have the `UnitPrice` in the second table so I can have a calculated column of the `ExtendedPrice`, unless there is a way to have a calculated column with values from another table.

```
CREATE TABLE ITEM 
    (
    ItemNumber int IDENTITY(1,1) Not NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    ItemName varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    OrderDate datetime NOT NULL,
    UnitPrice money NOT NULL,
    Description text NOT NULL,
    );  

CREATE TABLE ORDER_LINE_ITEM
    (
    OrderId int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES ORDERS(OrderID),
    LineNumber int NOT NULL,
    ItemNumber int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES ITEM(ItemNumber) NOT NULL,
    Quantity int Not NULL,
    UnitPrice money NOT NULL,
    ExtendedPrice money AS (Quantity * UnitPrice),
    CONSTRAINT pk_OrderLineItem PRIMARY KEY (OrderID,LineNumber)
    );
```

Comment: You give yourself a favor and don't do that. Just create both tables as they are and create a view on top of them having your calculations.

Comment: give your input and outpu to more understand

Answer (score 0):

Lets start with the problem at hand, from what you are asking you will just need to give it the **foreign key** and reference `ITEM(UnitPrice)`.

```
Insert into table ORDER_LINE_ITEM                  

CONSTRAINT FK_ORDER_LINE_ITEM_ITEM FOREIGN KEY(UNITPRICE) REFERENCE ITEM(UNITPRICE)
```

Second thing you need to work on is your overall coding style because you have two different ways of constraining **foreign keys** and **primary keys**. This will help with future coding work and if you are working with another coder on a project.